# ¿Cómo establecer inputs independientes a partir de filtros de una misma base en una shiny app?

Tags: r, filtro, shiny

Tengo una shiny app donde a partir de una misma base (iris) se generan dos tablas, mostrándose cada una en un tabItem diferente. La idea sería que el usuario pueda filtrar por especie para ver los resultados, pero como lo tengo armado ahora, ese filtro solo funciona en la tabla 1:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Especies"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tabla 1: sepal.lenght", tabName = "table", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Tabla 2: sepal.width", tabName = "table2", icon = icon("th"))
    )),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    
    tabItem(tabName = "table",
            fluidRow(column(selectInput("species", "Sepal.Length",choices = levels(iris$Species)),
                                        tableOutput(outputId = "table"),width = 12))),
    
    tabItem(tabName = "table2",
            fluidRow(column(selectInput("species", "Sepal.Width",choices = levels(iris$Species)),
                                        tableOutput(outputId = "table2"),width = 12))))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% 
      filter(Species == input$species)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    table(filtered_data()$Sepal.Length)
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    table(filtered_data()$Sepal.Width)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

¿Cómo debería hacer para que funcione el filtro en la tabla 2, siendo independiente del filtro en la tabla 1?